# how to combine two functions

Tags: node.js, mongoose

the first function:

```
getAllUserCars: (userEmail) => Car.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
            {
              from: 'users',
              localField: 'owner',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'ownerCar'
            }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'ownerCar.email': userEmail
      }
    }
  ])
```

the second function:

```
getAllUserCarsByStatus: (userEmail, status) => Car.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
          {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'owner',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'ownerCar'
          }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        'ownerCar.email': userEmail,
        status
      }
    }
  ])
```

maybe  can somehow skip this param,if you pass an empty object, it is an error or an empty tape

Comment: What is "this param"?

Comment: .status .param.

Comment: `getAllUserCarsByStatus:  (userEmail, status = { $exists : true }) => Car.aggregate([`

Answer (score 0):

can you try replacing match condition in your code by following code:

```
$match: {
    $and: [{
            'ownerCar.email': userEmail,
        }, {
            'status': status
        }]
}
```